# Different results on different computers

Tags: c, memory, allocation

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void red(int *);
int main()
{
    int *wsk,i;
    wsk = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        wsk[i]=i+100;
        printf("value: %d num pointer:%p \n",wsk[i],wsk+i);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    red(wsk);
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        printf("value: %d num pointer:%p \n",wsk[i],wsk+i);
    }
    free(wsk);
    return 0;
}
void red(int* wsk)
{
    int i;
    wsk = realloc(wsk,11*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        printf("value: %d num pointer:%p \n",wsk[i],wsk+i);
    }
}
```

On the school computer this code works and the `wsk` pointer in the function red is the same as in main. When I run the same code on a different computer I get different results

Results from my computer:

[image: in my computer]

Results from the other computer:

[image: other computer]

Comment: "Works there, not here" is usually the same as "has undefined behaviour".

Comment: `wsk` in the function is a **copy** of the `wsk` in `main`. It's reallocated value does not find its way back to `main`.

Comment: You're calling `realloc` within `red()`, but that pointer is not passed outside that function. You're likely invalidating `wsk` in the main function.

Comment: side note, [you should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/9614249)

Comment: C is pass-by-value.  Print out the value of the pointer `wsk` in `main()` before and after your call to `red(wsk);`.  You'll note that it doesn't change, even if the value *inside* your `red()` function does change.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic it was important more than 19 years ago before the C99 standard. Now unless you use the prehistoric C standard, functions with no prototypes are not allowed.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 brain fart? This question is not about function prototypes, or was a comment deleted?

Comment: casting malloc was dangerous if you had forgotten to include stdlib.h with the malloc prototype. Nowadays it does not matter as the "new" (almost 20 years old) C standard does not allow implicit function declarations.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, it is useless, nevertheless. Casts are bad, if you don't understand your witchcraft. And, BTW, many compilers still use the implicit `int` rule.

Comment: @JensGustedt - no programmers use old standards. In c99+ casts are even safer for the humans if you cast to the type which is sizeofed (compilers are ignoring them). Example: `double *f = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int))`.  - you will get the warning. Without the cast - no warning.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, and how do you guarantee that you always use the same type in the cast as in the `sizeof`? I probably also would get a warning for `double *f = (long*)malloc(n * sizeof(int))`. The recommended practice for such cases is to use `double *f = malloc(n * sizeof *f)` because it just never can go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The realloced address is only kept in the red function scope. Then you dereference the old pointer.

```
void red(int** wsk)
{
    int i;
    *wsk = realloc(*wsk,11*sizeof(int));
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's no need for an `int **`.  Just *return* the new value.

Comment: I do not change the initial OP idea. And it shows the scope of the variables

Comment: True, but I'd say the initial OP idea was fundamentally broken.  Adding pointer indirection might be a bit much for someone not familiar enough with C to know it's a pass-by-value language.

Comment: I did so, but my teacher said that the pointer to the pointer is not necessary because the tables are passed through the references

Comment: The teacher should learn something about the scopes of the variables.

Comment: ok, just how I did in school void red (int *wsk) and i changed the size of memory it worked well in main()

Comment: It is undefined behavior. Depending how the realloc works - it may keep the same start address or not. In this particular case in your school the realloced chunk of memory has the same start address. It is just incidental.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `void red(int* wsk)` passes the `wsk` [by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/9614249) meaning a local version of `wsk` is copied to the function and changes made within `red` will not be reflected in `main`.

One approach to solve this is to return the new value of `wsk` to main:

```
int* red(int* wsk) // Return type changed
{
    int i;
    wsk = realloc(wsk,11*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        printf("value: %d num pointer:%p \n",wsk[i],wsk+i);
    }

    return wsk; // Return new wsk
}
```

And then change the call in main to

```
wsk = red(wsk);
```

So that the `wsk` in `main` is updated to the `wsk` returned by `red`.

---

Also note that you never initialized `wsk[10]` after calling `realloc()` and accessing it will result in more undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that `wsk[10]` you are printing is an uninitialised value.

Comment: I know it but it does not matter, i only print wsk[10]

Comment: @aerodynamic96 even *reading* out of range is undefined behaviour. Just don't be careless with limits in C - there is no protection.